A simple logic control yet it does not work
I have two separate LEDs. Both LEDs have 500 ohm resistor and are powered with 5V. These LEDs are controlled by an MCU. LED anode is connected to VCC and the diode is connected through the resistor directly to a MCU GPIO port capable to drive the LED.
So I have two separate signals that controls LEDs and the VCC. Those are the only things that I can access. I have no access to GND. What I would like to do is a kind of logic that will ensure that only one of those two LEDs can glow. If MCU tries to turn on both LEDs none should glow.
In fact, this is not just a LED but a SSR module (G3MB-202P) with internal photodiode. the SSR controls a 230V AC motor. One SSR spins motor in one direction and second in the other. I just want to protect in case when the MCU will try to spin the motor in both directions as it would damage the motor.
My current approach is depicted below, but it does not seem to work. Could anyone please guide me how to do the logic properly?


If you want to add more images you need to [edit] your question. You can't add images here in the comments.

Really rough calculations. But looks like HFE is about 100 for a MMBT3904LT1. So IBE is (you didn't say at what voltage the MCU works at so lets assume worse case 3V) (3-.7)/4700 which is about 0.0005A.  Multiply by HFE gets you up to 5mA. And the suggested forward current of the G3MB 202P is 10mA (5mA is the lower limit ... but these calculations are very rough and the actual current may well be below 5mA).

...nuts, did not fix the above in time before the stackexchange comment editing timeout. Anyways it's wrong.... fixing it: (3-.7)/4700 which is about 0.0005A.  Multiply by HFE gets you up to 50mA. And the suggested forward current of the G3MB 202P is 10mA (max 20mA). But that's the current capacity of the transistor. There's also the limiting current of the MCU's output and a few other things to consider. So maybe the diode is burnt out or maybe not. Like I said ... rough calculations.

Question: Why can't you re-write the software for the logical behavior desired at GPIO0 and GPIO1 and connect each to a solid state relay? In the real world, this would be the accepted solution as it cuts the MMBT3904LT1 from the BOM reducing part count, reducing cost and lowering the MTB failure. I'll put this in an answer if you'll accept it. Otherwise, while addressing the problem, it does not directly answer the stated question.

Do you think replacing a transistor would do the thing? Or it is not that easy? The MCU GPIO logic is 5V.

@st2000 just delete the bad comment and write again

In your question you refer to 500 ohm resistors, but i don't see these in your schematic. Where exactly are they?

The resistor is in the G3MB-202P.

Your problem was that the transistor was inverting from the Base and non-inverting from the Emitter, so your XOR logic failed.
Using any CMOS logic level input, a simpler XOR solution works.
Your R values will yield an 8 mA LED current with 5V logic <~50 ohms.
A phototransistor was used to simulate the phototriac logic, so also disregard the 3.3V.
I changed the interface from high Enable input to low (!) Enable input which is safer during a power On Reset with all I/O's floating as inputs.

H/L inputs in box are interactive.

I like the solution. Very simple in implementation and will probably work. I'll test it today.

If I understood correctly, you made an anti-parallel LED connection. Just would like to point out that the LED's reverse breakdown voltage is 5V.

ohh, so it will not work!

@noonespecial well, let's say "not guaranteed" because some operating conditions will be either quite close to or beyond the maximum ratings. When you apply 5V to one input and 0V to the other, one of the LEDs will be exposed to a reverse voltage of 5V which is the abs max. So it's not guaranteed whether the LED will survive.

There is a fair bit of margin above -5V in my experience for IR LEDs only leak about -1uA at -5V and a lot more at -10V and high temp.  White LEDs leak about 10 uA @ -5 V.  But @RohatKılıç may have a different experience. If it makes you feel safer add a 1N4148 diode in series.

or  If it makes you feel safer add a 5K resistor in parallel to drop it 10%. but the Si diode will leak less and see most the -5V with 0V across the IR LED.

If you wanted to feel safer AND reuse the MMBT3904, short the Base-Collector and use it a leakage block for -5V and expect near -0V when IR is reversed instead of the 1N4148.  The forward drop in current is insignificant.  But I would use it as is after checking the 5V tolerances for < 2%.

Wow, so many good ideas. Thank you so much!


What I would like to do is a kind of logic that will ensure that only one of those two LEDs can glow. If MCU tries to turn on both LEDs none should glow.

This sounds like an XOR behaviour:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The above is a crude, two-transistor XNOR gate (NOT of XOR) and, of course, is for two inputs and one output yet you have two inputs and outputs. But I think you can make use of it somehow.

Yes, kind like a XOR but not exactly. This is what I tried to achieve in the circuit I shared above.

Agreed. @noonespecial
Q2-e must be grounded to be a valid XNOR in RTL.

Your circuit really should work, but only if the Input0 and Input1 pins can source current. I suspect that they can only sink current — i.e., they are open-collector or open-drain outputs — therefore neither transistor can turn on.
If this is the case, just modify your resistor position slightly to use them as pull-ups:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

You could just connect both SSR inputs to both GPIO0 and GPIO1 if those and VCC are only available signals.
Then you can't light up both LEDs simultaneously.
However, this offers no safety. You can blink both LEDs on and off so fast that the motor or SSRs still burn, if something goes wrong.
Of course you can make software whigh delays the correct amount with both off for some time before activating one SSR.

Good point indicating the issue with fast toggling. And no, I cannot modify the software.
